# Regex for ending string and containing two other strings

Tags: regex

Conditions:

1. End with `abc` AND include `123`
2. Include `456`

My current regex is `(abc$)(123)|456` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Include 123 *and* 456 *or* 456?

Comment: What's the relationship between 1 and 2? Is that an OR?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(?=.*456).*123.*abc$
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*456)` - a positive lookahead that requires any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then `456` immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `123` - a literal value
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `abc` - an `abc` string
- `$` - end of string.